# Alternative to saving matplotlib figure locally to insert into markdown document created in Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, matplotlib, markdown

I'm using [MdUtils](https://mdutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Example_Python.html) to create a markdown document in Python that includes Matplotlib figures. At the moment, I'm having to save those figures to a directory, either in PNG or HTML format, and then call those images back with a path in a MdUtils method.

This function returns a matplotlib figure

```
matplotlib_figure = matplotlib_figure_maker(df)
```

Then I save it

```
plt.savefig('/path/to/image.png')
```

Then I insert it with "new_inline_image"

```
mdFile.new_paragraph(
    mdFile.new_inline_image(text='', path='/path/to/image.png')
)
```

I haven't been able to find a way, with MdUtils or any other Python markdown document package, to insert the matplotlib figure into the markdown document without first saving it. You can also view the issue I raised on GitHub [here](https://github.com/didix21/mdutils/issues/52). I'm worried about the inefficiency of the code running like this and have trouble believing this is what anyone who creates markdown documents with images in Python has to do, but so far I haven't found any alternatives.

Comment: Eh, it's kinda of the way to do it. It really depends on how much efficiency you're looking for. For example, when I write a report in LaTex that has some python data science behind it, I run the python when I need it redone and then the LaTeX to render it. Doing so in the terminal is easier since you can hop around with arrow keys. Apologies if this doesn't help, but wanted to provide insight for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info — it's better to know it's not possible than to continue searching for a method that doesn't exist. If you're sure there's no way to do it, feel free to give that as an answer, if you can give some explanation for why this isn't a functionality for markdown tools in Python.

Comment: No problem, I can't give it as answer because I'm not 100% sure. Also, my answer is personal preference since I ultimately use a custom bash command that works through pandoc and a python main.py file. Which, I have to edit and save for each report. Do you want me to leave an answer showing you a bash command with pandoc/main.py?

Comment: Sure; that seems like a helpful possible workaround.

Comment: My mistake, I misread your question. The answer you're looking for lies in https://wiki.python.org/moin/BytesIO, where you take the "bytes" of the image and insert them at runtime. I have never gotten this to work how I wanted, and tried a few times. But, I always default back to keeping the images. So, I still won't post an answer to follow stack rules. Hope that helps.

Comment: At the end of the day, a markdown file with embedded media requires you to also provide said media and link it there. If you're really worried about efficiency, i.e. having tons and tons of images to output, I recommend parallelizing the processes.

Comment: @zerecess seems to be indicating that this is not the case; that image bytes can be inserted at runtime.